# What is a "key cell"?

Tags: chord-progressions, modulation, roman-numerals

I have recently heard of the concept of a "key cell" as a short modulation (number of bars) that contains a tonal model progression, which can be analyzed in the context of two closely related keys.
Can anybody elaborate?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean model or modal?

Comment: Can you tell is where you heard the term, and in what musical context?

Comment: A Google search will confirm that this isn't a generally used musical term.  So you must refer to the teacher or book which coined it.

Comment: The term was used for harmonic analysis of Chopin's Prelude op. 28 no. 20.

Comment: I meant "model", not "modal". Specifically the progression iii-vi-IV/ii etc.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I did some Googling and could find a grand total of 1 resource that specifically mentioned a *"Key Cell"* and, sure enough, it was referring to short, temporary, modulations.

That paper is here: [A Musical Discussion and Analysis of Romance sans Paroles by Three French Composers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBqa7bw5bYAhUJPiYKHbUgDRUQFggxMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcardinalscholar.bsu.edu%2Fbitstream%2F123456789%2F197785%2F1%2FHwangH_2013-1_BODY.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1e--NoHFY9PkNHfXLk1PLU)

However, he never makes any mention of any *"models"*, but **does** refer to short *"modal"* modulations within the context of those *"key cells"*.

So, in short, a "key cell" is, as you mentioned, simply a short modulation; And, that it is possible for a short modulation to be one where, instead of modulating to `Am` by resolving `E7` to `Am`, we see the piece moving from `Em` to `Am` as the sign that the piece has 'modulated', temporarily, to `Am` (and the progression of `Em` to `Am` is considered modal within this "key cell" context).

However, like a previous person had noted, this is not common terminology and would likely only serve to confuse if attempted to be used with someone who was not specifically aware of that *"key cell"* concept.